# TypeError: Openurl() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'

Tags: python, tkinter

Everything is normal, but when I click my button it gives me an error I can't seem to fix:

> TypeError: Openurl() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'

Here's the code

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import ttk
import webbrowser

root = Tk()

url = 'mylink.com/lol'
def Openurl(url):

  w = Label(root, text="Where can I take you?")
  w.pack()

button = Button(root, text="Open Owners Profile #1", command=Openurl)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Apparently you need to provide an url to Openurl function but you don't.

Comment: I don't understand?

Comment: you can only use `command = Openurl` when the function does not contain any arguments. Because `Openurl(url)` has one argument you must pass something to the function. In you case you need to use `command = lambda: Openurl(url)`. Thought I think you may not fully understand how functions work judging by your comment to taras.

Comment: Guys, I'm a newbie working hard to make my first application..

Comment: Guys, I'm a newbie working hard to make my first application.. Please help me. Okay, I managed to create another function like that, But. the button2 is not showing up. Please don't give me negative reputations. I'm new to this forum with 0 knowledge.

Comment: & I came here thinking this community was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Openurl` function takes in an argument `url` which you are not passing in.

This should work

```
button = Button(root, text="Open Owners Profile #1", command=lambda: Openurl(url))
```

Comment: On click it's prints the label.. Any idea why? :c

Comment: That is what you are telling it to do. The `command` argument takes 
 in a function that is called when the button is clicked.